# iOS/Androind apps for Beamer

Tags: beamer

Can anyone suggest an app for iOS/Android (hopefully a free app) that supports Beamer viewer? PDF viewer is good except that is does not go with the transitions and stops. Thank you very much.

Comment: Is this question not for other sites like [ask different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/183726/zyy)?

Comment: to use transitions, you need a pdf viewer capable of JavaScript, maybe https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/41806/mobile-pdf-reader-with-javascript-support could help

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  better suited for softwarerecs.stackexchange.com or one of the stacks which deal with ios or android